# isEqualToString doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

For some reason when I do a `[string isEqualToString:string`] I get a "NO".

In the picture "item" was declared as a `@property NSString *item;`  I originally declared it as a plain `NSString *item` but it still didnt work.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Here is the code,  I tried to do a screen shot to show the debugger output, but not enough reputation.

```
- (IBAction)playCourseSelection:(id)sender
{
    // Get File Directory
    NSArray *arrayPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [arrayPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [docDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/playCourse.txt"];

    // Write String for course
    NSString *writeString = item;

    BOOL test;

    test = [item isEqualToString:@"Add Course..."];

    if (test)
    {
        writeString = @"";
    };

    [writeString writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    // Close the file
}
```

---

```
self            EditCourseViewController *  0x0848c770
test            BOOL    '\0'
writeString NSString *  0x07676b80
item            NSString *  0x07676b80
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please format your code.

Comment: Where do you initialize item? What's the output of: NSLog(@"Item: %@\n", item); ?

Comment: [item isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",str1]];

Comment: @FaJitendraDeore, what is that trying to achieve?

Comment: 2013-08-03 17:14:13.826 GolfScorecard[28156:c07] Item: Add Course…
2013-08-03 17:14:13.828 GolfScorecard[28156:c07] writeString: Add Course…
2013-08-03 17:14:13.828 GolfScorecard[28156:c07] Test: 0

Comment: I am trying to compare two strings. If they are equal I want to write a null value to a file.  If they are different, I want to write the string to a file.

Comment: Suggestion: Set a breakpoint at "if (test)". Check there the value of "item". If it is what you expect @"Add Course...", check that your string literal @"Add Course..." with that it is compared does not contain any invisible characters, and check that "..." is in both cases either three dots or the single special character "...".

Comment: @Mike Try to write a complete example in [CodeRunner](http://krillapps.com/coderunner/) or http://ideone.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@"Add Course..." is not equal to item.

if u see NSLog(@"item is %@",item);   console print `" item is (null)"`

So [item `isEqualToString`:@"Add Course..."] is NO

Answer (score -2):

I figured out the answer.  Who knew it would take forever (like all day).  So I guess XCode recognizes the points of ellipsis (...) and assigns them a value different than three periods.  I removed the three periods and it works:

[image]

Comment: This is not correct. Xcode doesn't replace the characters “...” or the single character ‘…’. Example: `NSLog(@"%d", [@"Add Course..." isEqualToString:@"Add Course..."]);` prints 1.

Comment: Jano, you might be right, but XCode did not treat "Add Course..." correctly.  My only suspect is that the "..." were not treated as a true string.  When I removed "..." from the end of the string, everything worked correctly.

Comment: Something else is going on. You could try posting the complete code here, or even the whole project in github, or test a sample on CodeRunner or ideone.com.